# Encryption mechanism for local TCP communication

Tags: ssl, encryption, tcp

Sorry I'm not a cyber security expert but I'm looking for some insight! I would like to encrypt a standard TCP socket communication and thought about using SSL. Both devices might not be connected to the Internet and cannot communicate with a root CA to validate their certificates. This should do the trick to prevent sniffing the communication but doesn't protect agains man in the middle attack.

Alternatively, devices could generate and sign each other certificates but how to make this procedure secure?

Since it's pretty easy to hack, it probably doesn't worth the effort to implment ... Right? Or what encryption mechanism would you recommend?

Comment: SSL does not require communicating with a root CA when establishing a connection, and there are other solutions to the signing issue: you can use self-signed certificates if you can arrange for the peers to trust each others'; although frankly self-signed certificates are more trouble than the few dollars they save you.

Comment: if you have tamper proof devices you could embed CA into devices and sign certs on the fly and companion devices would trust such certificates. But you could then use the same cert on all devices without having CA at all because you could check the cert yourself by comparing remote cert with local private key. But if someone can dump software out of your devices then such approach does not make any sense.

Comment: And I don't know why you think communicating with a CA would enable sniffing even if it happened, or why SSL is 'pretty easy to hack'. It most certainly is not.

Answer (score 0):

> Both devices might not be connected to the Internet and cannot communicate with a root CA to validate their certificates. This should do the trick to prevent sniffing the communication but doesn't protect agains man in the middle attack.

Not true. If a device is unable to reach internet, it would be unable to check certificate revocation (CRL/OCSP) . The client would still be able to validate the other's party certificate and its validity.

> Alternatively, devices could generate and sign each other certificates but how to make this procedure secure?

You don't really need to sign each other's certificate, the parties just need to trust them.

As already commented, you can use a self-signed CA or a self-signed certificate and then there's a question how do you protect the generated and CA private keys (isn't that always the case?). IMHO - even without any internet access using the qualified certificates (signed by a trusted CA)  is a good /best option.

> pretty easy to hack.. Or what encryption mechanism would you recommend?

No, not really "easy to hack" provided you keep the private keys private.

I'd say SSL is the best option for ensuring confidentiality and integrity of the transport channels.